# model objects between controler

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

i have a controller `A` call view with an argument of a model like this

```
public class ControllerA : Controller
public ActionResult f1 (){
    model1.ID=1;
    return View(model1);
    }
}
```

the view will make some changes then send the `model1` object to another controller like this, the another controller, which is B, is like this:

```
public class ControllerB : Controller
    public ActionResult f2(model1){
       ...
       return View();
    }
}
```

inside the `f2` i check for the modelstate and it is valided, but my problem is that the `model1` object in the `f2` doesnt contrain that value of ID **even though i print the `model1.ID` in the view and it is correct.**

**why please?**

#### note that i didnt change the value of ID inside the view, i just print it

Answer (score 0):

MVC is a stateless framework, stateless means that HTTP doesn't have built in support for states. If you want to pass a value from a controller to another,you can use session or application in MVC project.See below:

[Passing value across multiple Controllers](http://forums.asp.net/p/1801681/4977471.aspx?Re%20Passing%20value%20across%20multiple%20Controllers)